# HMENU for a window in Win32 API

Tags: c++, winapi

When compiling the following piece of code:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

HINSTANCE mainHinst;
HWND mainWindow;

int CALLBACK WinMain(
        HINSTANCE hInst,
        HINSTANCE hPrevInst,
        LPSTR     pCmdLine,
        int       nCmdShow)
{
    mainHinst = hInst;
    LPCSTR className = "Best Window in the entire UNIVERSE.";

    WNDCLASSEX wc = { 0 };
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(wc);
    wc.style = CS_OWNDC;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = mainHinst;
    wc.hIcon = nullptr;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = nullptr;
    wc.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    wc.lpszClassName = className;
    wc.hIconSm = nullptr;

    RegisterClassEx( &wc );

    mainWindow = CreateWindowEx(
            0, className,
            "変態",
            WS_BORDER | WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU,
            CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 640, 480,
            nullptr, (HMENU)-1, mainHinst, nullptr // here
            );

    ShowWindow(mainWindow, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(mainWindow);

    MSG msg;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    
    return msg.wParam;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(69);
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

This compiles for `MSVC` and `g++` but shows no window but shows as a process in the Task Manager. But if the `HMENU` set to `nullptr` or `NULL` it compiles and shows a window when executed.

```cpp
mainWindow = CreateWindowEx(
            0, className,
            "変態",
            WS_BORDER | WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU,
            CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 640, 480,
            nullptr, nullptr, mainHinst, nullptr // here
            );
```

This shows a window && process in Task Manager && icon on TaskBar.

***So, is there any way for a window to have a `HMENU` set to some value?***

Comment: Start by checking the results of the WinAPI function calls and calling GetLastError if they fail.  Ad any failing function call and the result of GetLastError to the post.

Answer (score 2):

For `WS_CHILD` windows `HMENU` parameter is actually control ID, and can be any integer, but for `WS_POPUP` / `WS_OVERLAPPED` it means actual menu handle.

You don't pass explicitly one for these three styles, so it is implicitly `WS_OVERLAPPED`, because `WS_OVERLAPPED == 0`. So you should pass a menu handle. Like one you get from `LoadMenu` or `CreateMenu`.

As you didn't, it is likely that `CreateWindowEx` failed, and you don't have a window. Yet your program sits in task manager, as it spins the message loop.

Comment: Would you know where to find the control IDs?

Comment: @GregorWattersHärtl, it is arbitrary value that you can pick on your own (though you should prefer yo avoid duplicate IDs)